# Product/Store Data Deployment Best Practices

Tags: magento2, deployment, data

I'm currently working on a store with Pipeline deployment and in the [docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/deployment/pipeline/) for the Production system it states that:

> You should make minimal configuration changes here and no changes to websites, stores, store views, products, or the catalog. You should make all those types of changes in your development system.

The configuration being done on the development makes sense to me as that's easily trackable in version control. But, the actual data such as products/categories/cms data, seems a bit backwards to handle it that way, especially when people other than a developer will be making changes to the store. You can have a staging server that those changes are made and the data is eventually migrated to production, but seems unnecessary for that, unless if I'm missing something?

Is it fundamentally wrong to keep that data in production only? Or, am I fundamentally wrong and staging that data is best? I've always had production be the source of truth for that data as it made it far easier for other people managing stores to make edits/add product/store data, but with Magento stating that's wrong, making me rethink everything.

What are your guys' thoughts on this? How do you handle it?